# Accessing props gives undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I've got a component where I pass children components using the `props.children` parameter. But when I try to access the props in the following code, I get an undefined error.

```
if (children && React.isValidElement(children)) {
    avatar = React.cloneElement(avatarProp, {
        className: classNames(classes.avatar, avatarProp.props.className),
        childrenClassName: classNames(classes.avatarChildren, avatarProp.props.childrenClassName),
    });
}
```

I call the component using the following code.

```
<Chip label="This is a sample chip">
    <Avatar backgroundColor="#333" size="100" />
</Chip>
```

even though I access the parameter in the component logic, the pop is optional to be passed. How can I resolve this issue?

```
main.bundle.js:53409 TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatar' of undefined
    at Chip.render (main.bundle.js:77126)
    at main.bundle.js:31358
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (main.bundle.js:30638)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (main.bundle.js:31357)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (main.bundle.js:31384)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (main.bundle.js:30924)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (main.bundle.js:30820)
    at Object.mountComponent (main.bundle.js:5115)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (main.bundle.js:30193)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (main.bundle.js:28381)
```

---

classes variable inside render method

```
render() {

    let defaultClasses = 'chips chips-rounded',
        defaultLabelClasses = 'chips-label',
        avatar = null,
        deleteIcon = '';

    const {
        classes,
        children,
        onClick,
        label,
        onRequestDelete,
        labelStyle,
    } = this.props;

    if (children && React.isValidElement(children)) {
        avatar = React.cloneElement(children, {
            className: classNames(classes.avatar, children.props.className),
            childrenClassName: classNames(classes.avatarChildren, children.props.childrenClassName),
        });
    }

    if(onRequestDelete){
        deleteIcon = (
            <div className="deleteIcon" onClick={this.handleDeleteIconClick} />
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className={classNames(classes, defaultClasses)} onClick={onClick} >
            {avatar}
            <span className={classNames(labelStyle, defaultLabelClasses)}>{label}</span>
            {deleteIcon}
        </div>
    )
}
```

classes variable defined using proptypes

```
const propTypes = {
    /*
     * Used to extend default object classes
     */
    classes : PropTypes.object,
    /*
     * Click event handler
     */
    onClick : PropTypes.func,
    /*
     * Delete event handler
     */
    onRequestDelete : PropTypes.func,
    /*
     * This property will contain label text
     */
    label : PropTypes.string,
    /*
     * This property will contain label styling
     */
    labelStyle : PropTypes.object
}
```

Comment: where do you define `classes`?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Show the entire render function

Comment: updated as per request! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want classes to be optional then you need to check that in your code. There is no pretty way to do that.
Use a ternary operator to keep the if else as short as possible and use an empty string when no prop named classes is passed to the component.

**Example:**

```
if (children && React.isValidElement(children)) {
  const avatarClasses = classes ? classes.avatar : '';
  const avatarChildrenClasses = classes ? classes.avatarChildren : '';

  avatar = React.cloneElement(children, {
    className: classNames(avatarClasses, children.props.className),
    childrenClassName: classNames(avatarChildrenClasses, 
    children.props.childrenClassName),
  });
}
```